# How to display a recaptcha error within the submitted form's page?

Tags: php, html

I am using the recaptcha widget on a contact form, i was wondering how would you be able to display the error the user would gets on the same page instead of going to another page and displaying the error.

Comment: You could use ajax to send the response and return a success/fail status. I'm not sure about the security vulnerabilities this poses though.

Comment: How would i go around doing so?

Comment: The easiest way is probably to have a look at: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: This is my code for the php:
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "6Lf41e8SAAAAACG-jlaH5YZcMNlGpiIBhBSs-vy_";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
 } else ?>

Answer (score 1):

You can put your form to submit on the same page, and check the post data on PHP side.
Check this example:

```
<?php 
$captcha = $_POST['captcha'];
if(isset($captcha)) {
  $captcha_answer = // you need to put your correct captcha answer here
  if($captcha == $captcha_answer) {
      // captcha is correct, continue.
  }
  else {
      // captcha is not correct, display error message.
      echo '<div style="background-color:red; padding:3px;">Your captcha is not correct, please try again.</div>';
      echo '<form method="post">
                <input type="text" name="captcha" value="Type captcha here" />
            </form>'; // print the page again
  }
}
else {
?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="captcha" value="Type captcha here" />
</form>

<?php } ?>
```

Another option is to use JavaScript with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

[Click here for demo](http://vitawebsitedesign.com.au/stackoverflow/index.htm)

Enter "CORRECT-CAPTCHA" and click "check" button

---

**html:**

```
<input type="text" id="captcha"/>                 <!-- textbox to hold captcha text -->
<button id="check-captcha">check</button>         <!-- button to check captcha -->
<div id="error-message"></div>                    <!-- to show error message -->

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#check-captcha").on("click", function() {  // On button click
            $.ajax({                                  // Call PHP script to check captcha
                url: "checkCaptcha.php",
                method: "post",
                data: {
                    "captcha": $("#captcha").val()    // Textbox holding captcha text
                }
            }).done(function(error) {                 // On PHP script finish..
                $("#error-message").text(error)       // Show correct/wrong message
            });             
        });
    });
</script>
```

**php:**

```
<?php
    $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];           // Get captcha text from textbox
    if ($captcha == 'CORRECT-CAPTCHA') {    // If text == correct captcha
        echo 'correct';                     // Show message
    } else {
        echo 'error';                       // Show error
    }
?>
```

---

**I assume your new to AJAX, so heres an explanation on what's going on:**

An "AJAX call" is just used to execute a PHP script, from JavaScript.

1. Button clicked
2. JavaScript code executed
3. AJAX call done to execute PHP script
4. PHP script executed, and returns message to JavaScript
5. Show message in div element